# having trouble connecting Visual studio 2019 with MySQL database and inserting user input in textboxes into said database (solved)

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, connection-string, database-connection

i am using Visual Studio 2019 and MySQL workbench, i've created a database specifically for the program, and also created a table for collecting user info. what i want to do is have the user input data into textboxes and then when they press a button the info then needs to be uploaded into the table in the corresponding headings. i've had issues trying to debugg the code ranging from System.Nullreference exceptions relating to "ispasswordexpired" and something about server thread. i tried fixing the issues but it seems that i have just broken it further.
here is the code:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using MySqlX.XDevAPI;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Tidal_Waves_Information
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public string ConnectionString { get; private set; }

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 Start_Page = new Form1();
            Start_Page.Show();
        }


        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString: "Server=localhost;port=3306;Database=tidal_waves_db;Uid=root;Pwd=*********"))
                {

                    string Query = "INSERT INTO user_details_table (Username, First_Name, Surname, Password, Email, Mobile_Phone) VALUES (@Username, @First_Name, @Surname, @Password, @Email, @Mobile_Phone)";

                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = connection;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", textBox1.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First_Name", textBox5.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", textBox6.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", textBox2.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", textBox3.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile_Phone", textBox4.Text);
                    connection.Open();
                    MySqlDataReader MyReader;
                    MyReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    MessageBox.Show("Save Data");
                    while (MyReader.Read())
                    {
                    }

                    connection.Close();


                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

I've tried googling how to do this and have tried looking on stack overflow. (maybe im just searching wrong) but after multiple websites and attempts at integrating code it has led to no avail.
any help you guys could give would be greatly appreciated

Found a way to solve this.

```
MySqlConnection cnn;
string connectionString = "server=localhost;database=tidal_waves_db;uid=root;pwd=*******";
            cnn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
try
                {
                    cnn.Open();
                    MessageBox.Show("Connecting to database");

                    MySqlCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO user_details_table (Username, Password, First_Name, Surname, Email, Mobile_Phone, Address) VALUES (@Username, @Password, @First_Name, @Surname, @Email, @Mobile_Phone, @Address)";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", textBox1.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", textBox2.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First_Name", textBox3.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", textBox4.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", textBox5.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile_Phone", textBox6.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", listBox1.SelectedIndex);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cnn.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Upload Successful");

                }

                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("An error occurred");
                }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow, i would recommend adding the error that you are getting when trying to run your code, also the callstack. Also if your new to C# and database communication i would recommend reading about ORM's. Also i would highly recommend trying out EntityFramework you can find how to use EntityFramework with MySql here https://www.devjockeys.com/blog/c-sharp/using-entity-framework-with-mysql-a-code-first-example/

Comment: @Scary, can you possibly tell me which line throws the exception? And what is the specific exception? If possible, you can provide the database table designer with me so that I can know your problem clearly.